# How I can create a function() which one paremeter which is map

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void print( string::size_type n, string const & s )
{
    if( n == string::npos ) {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    } else {
        cout << "found: " << s.substr( n ) << '\n';
    }
}

//////I WANT HERE A FUNCTION WITH ONE PAREMETR - MAP///////

int main()
{
    map < char, int > pythagorean, simpleeng, gfive;

    pythagorean[ 'A' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'a' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'B' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'b' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'C' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'c' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'D' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'd' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'E' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'e' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'F' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'f' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'G' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'g' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'H' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'h' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'I' ] = 9;
    pythagorean[ 'i' ] = 9;
    pythagorean[ 'J' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'j' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'K' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'k' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'L' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'l' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'M' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'm' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'N' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'n' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'O' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'o' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'P' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'p' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'Q' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'q' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'R' ] = 9;
    pythagorean[ 'r' ] = 9;
    pythagorean[ 'S' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 's' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'T' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 't' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'U' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'u' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'V' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'v' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'W' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'w' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'X' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'x' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'Y' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'y' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'Z' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'z' ] = 8;


    simpleeng[ 'A' ] = 1;
    simpleeng[ 'a' ] = 1;
    simpleeng[ 'B' ] = 2;
    simpleeng[ 'b' ] = 2;
    simpleeng[ 'C' ] = 3;
    simpleeng[ 'c' ] = 3;
    simpleeng[ 'D' ] = 4;
    simpleeng[ 'd' ] = 4;
    simpleeng[ 'E' ] = 5;
    simpleeng[ 'e' ] = 5;
    simpleeng[ 'F' ] = 6;
    simpleeng[ 'f' ] = 6;
    simpleeng[ 'G' ] = 7;
    simpleeng[ 'g' ] = 7;
    simpleeng[ 'H' ] = 8;
    simpleeng[ 'h' ] = 8;
    simpleeng[ 'I' ] = 9;
    simpleeng[ 'i' ] = 9;
    simpleeng[ 'J' ] = 1;
    simpleeng[ 'j' ] = 1;
    simpleeng[ 'K' ] = 2;
    simpleeng[ 'k' ] = 2;
    simpleeng[ 'L' ] = 3;
    simpleeng[ 'l' ] = 3;
    simpleeng[ 'M' ] = 4;
    simpleeng[ 'm' ] = 4;
    simpleeng[ 'N' ] = 5;
    simpleeng[ 'n' ] = 5;
    simpleeng[ 'O' ] = 6;
    simpleeng[ 'o' ] = 6;
    simpleeng[ 'P' ] = 7;
    simpleeng[ 'p' ] = 7;
    simpleeng[ 'Q' ] = 8;
    simpleeng[ 'q' ] = 8;
    simpleeng[ 'R' ] = 9;
    simpleeng[ 'r' ] = 9;
    simpleeng[ 'S' ] = 1;
    simpleeng[ 's' ] = 1;
    simpleeng[ 'T' ] = 2;
    simpleeng[ 't' ] = 2;
    simpleeng[ 'U' ] = 3;
    simpleeng[ 'u' ] = 3;
    simpleeng[ 'V' ] = 4;
    simpleeng[ 'v' ] = 4;
    simpleeng[ 'W' ] = 5;
    simpleeng[ 'w' ] = 5;
    simpleeng[ 'X' ] = 6;
    simpleeng[ 'x' ] = 6;
    simpleeng[ 'Y' ] = 7;
    simpleeng[ 'y' ] = 7;
    simpleeng[ 'Z' ] = 8;
    simpleeng[ 'z' ] = 8;


    gfive[ 'A' ] = 7;
    gfive[ 'a' ] = 7;
    gfive[ 'B' ] = 8;
    gfive[ 'b' ] = 8;
    gfive[ 'C' ] = 1;
    gfive[ 'c' ] = 1;
    gfive[ 'D' ] = 2;
    gfive[ 'd' ] = 2;
    gfive[ 'E' ] = 3;
    gfive[ 'e' ] = 3;
    gfive[ 'F' ] = 4;
    gfive[ 'f' ] = 4;
    gfive[ 'G' ] = 5;
    gfive[ 'g' ] = 5;
    gfive[ 'H' ] = 6;
    gfive[ 'h' ] = 6;
    gfive[ 'I' ] = 7;
    gfive[ 'i' ] = 7;
    gfive[ 'J' ] = 8;
    gfive[ 'j' ] = 8;
    gfive[ 'K' ] = 9;
    gfive[ 'k' ] = 9;
    gfive[ 'L' ] = 1;
    gfive[ 'l' ] = 1;
    gfive[ 'M' ] = 2;
    gfive[ 'm' ] = 2;
    gfive[ 'N' ] = 3;
    gfive[ 'n' ] = 3;
    gfive[ 'O' ] = 4;
    gfive[ 'o' ] = 4;
    gfive[ 'P' ] = 5;
    gfive[ 'p' ] = 5;
    gfive[ 'Q' ] = 6;
    gfive[ 'q' ] = 6;
    gfive[ 'R' ] = 7;
    gfive[ 'r' ] = 7;
    gfive[ 'S' ] = 8;
    gfive[ 's' ] = 8;
    gfive[ 'T' ] = 9;
    gfive[ 't' ] = 9;
    gfive[ 'U' ] = 1;
    gfive[ 'u' ] = 1;
    gfive[ 'V' ] = 2;
    gfive[ 'v' ] = 2;
    gfive[ 'W' ] = 3;
    gfive[ 'w' ] = 3;
    gfive[ 'X' ] = 4;
    gfive[ 'x' ] = 4;
    gfive[ 'Y' ] = 5;
    gfive[ 'y' ] = 5;
    gfive[ 'Z' ] = 6;
    gfive[ 'z' ] = 6;




    int cho = 0, d;
    char o;
    string phrasetwo;

    while(1)
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
        cin >> phrasetwo;
        istringstream asd( phrasetwo );

        if ( !( asd >> d ) || asd >> o )
        {
            system( "cls" );
            cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cho = stoi( phrasetwo );
            if( cho <= 3 && cho >= 1 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    switch( cho )
    {
    case 1:
        {
            cout << "You chose Pythagorean MAP" << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            cout << "You chose Simpleeng MAP" << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            cout << "You chose Gfive MAP" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }




///////EVERYTHING DOWN SHOULD BE ADDED INTO FUNCTION/////////////

    string::size_type n;
    ifstream input( "words.txt" );
    ofstream output( "results.txt" );
    string str, phrase;
    int counter = 0, cnt = 0, choice = 0, chosennum = 0, asd = 0, x;
    bool flag;
    char c;


    while(1)
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to check:" << '\n' << "1) Number" << '\n' << "2) Phrase" << endl;
        cin >> phrase;
        istringstream s( phrase );

        if ( !( s >> x ) || s >> c )
        {
            system( "cls" );
            cout << "You want to check:" << '\n' << "1) Number" << '\n' << "2) Phrase" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = stoi( phrase );
            if( choice <= 2 && choice >= 1 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    switch( choice )
    {
        case 1:
            {
                cout << "Which number do you want to check?: ";
                while(1)
                {
                    cin >> phrase;
                    istringstream s( phrase );

                    if ( !( s >> x ) || s >> c )
                    {
                        cout << endl << "Which number do you want to check?: ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chosennum = stoi( phrase );
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cout << endl << "All words found: " << endl;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                do
                {
                    flag = false;
                    cout << "Which phrase do you want to check?: ";
                    cin >> phrase;

                    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
                    {
                        if ( isdigit( phrase[ i ] ) )
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                        cout << endl;
                } while (flag == true);

                for( char charr: phrase )
                {
                        chosennum += pythagorean[ charr ];
                }
                cout << '\t' << phrase << " in Pythagorean Gematria = " << chosennum << endl << endl << "All words found: " << endl;
                break;
            }
    }

    while( getline( input, str ) )
    {
        int sum = 0;

        n = str.find( ',' );

        if (n != string::npos)
        {
            str.resize( n );
        }

        for( char charr: str )
        {
            sum += pythagorean[ charr ];
        }

        if( sum == chosennum )
        {
            cout << '\t' << "Pythagorean: " << str << "(" << sum << ")" << '\n';
            output << "Pythagorean: " << '\t' << str << " = " << sum << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n You have found: " << counter << " words" << '\n';
    output << "\n\n You have found: " << counter << " words" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have declared 3 different maps `pythagorean`, `simpleeng`, and `gfive`. They have different values for characters, and I want to create one function which will calculate a sum in this loop:

```
for( char charr: str )
{
    sum += pythagorean[ charr ];
}
```

In 3 different ways, via using the `pythagorean`, `simpleeng`, and `gfive` maps.

For example, I run the program and I have to chosen 1-3 option:

```
Pythagorean Gematria, Simple/English, Gematria with G = 7
```

If I chose number 1, the program will calculate everything using the `pythagorean` map, and so on.

I'm looking for help because it looks like I'm doing something wrong and I really need this.

```
int cho = 0, d;
char o;
string phrasetwo;

while(1)
{
    system( "cls" );
    cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
    cin >> phrasetwo;
    istringstream asd( phrasetwo );

    if ( !( asd >> d ) || asd >> o )
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cho = stoi( phrasetwo );
        if( cho <= 3 && cho >= 1 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

switch( cho )
{
    case 1:
    {
        cout << "You chose Pythagorean MAP" << endl; ///HERE I WANT SUM FROM USING PYTHAGOREAN MAP/// LIKE FUNCTION ASD(PYTHAGOREAN MAP)
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        cout << "You chose Simpleeng MAP" << endl; ///HERE I WANT SUM FROM USING SIMPLEENG MAP/// LIKE FUNCTION ASD(SIMPLEENG MAP)
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        cout << "You chose Gfive MAP" << endl; ///HERE I WANT SUM FROM USING GFIVE MAP/// LIKE FUNCTION ASD(GFIVE MAP)
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way you create any other function that as a variable in a parameter. i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <map>

int get_map_sum(std::map<char, int>& my_map) {
    return std::accumulate(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), 0,  [](int acc, const std::map<char, int>::value_type& p){ return acc + p.second; });
}

int main() {
    std::map<char, int> pythagorean = {
        {'A', 1},
        {'a', 1},
        {'B', 2},
        {'b', 2},
        // ... So on and so forth
    };
    std::cout << get_map_sum(pythagorean) << std::endl;
    // Output is 6, as expected.
}
```

I would suggest using the initializing format for the map that I have used, as it is less typing and cleaner to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Create sub function to create map:

```
std::map<char, int> make_pythagorean_map()
{
    return {
        {'A', 1},
        {'a', 1},
        {'B', 2},
        {'b', 2},
// ..
        {'Z', 8},
        {'z', 8}
    };
}

std::map<char, int> make_simpleeng_map()
{
    return {
        {'A', 1},
        {'a', 1},
        {'B', 2},
        {'b', 2},
// ..
        {'Z', 8},
        {'z', 8}
    };
}

std::map<char, int> make_gfive_map()
{
    return {
        {'A', 7},
        {'a', 7},
        {'B', 8},
        {'b', 8},
// ..
        {'Z', 6},
        {'z', 6}
    };
}
```

then

```
std::map<char, int> select_map(int choice)
{
    switch( choice )
    {
        case 1:
        {
            std::cout << "You chose Pythagorean MAP" << std::endl;
            return make_pythagorean_map();
        }
        case 2:
        {
            std::cout << "You chose Simpleeng MAP" << std::endl;
            return make_simpleeng_map();
        }
        case 3:
        {
            std::cout << "You chose Gfive MAP" << std::endl;
            return make_gfive_map();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main you have

```
auto m = select_map(cho);
// use m instead of std::map<char, int> pythagorean
```